# Django Open rendered HTML file

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

Guys i want to open rendered HTML file when i am clicking a image on my HTML page. How i should use it?

**HTML code fragment**

```
<header>
    <nav class="headlist">
        <a href='{% url **Link to home_view** %}'><img id = "img1" src="{% static 'css/logo.png' %}" alt="logo"></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="{% url **Link to about_view** %}">O nas</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url **Link to contact_view** %}">Kontakt</a></li>
            <li><a>Zajęcia</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

**main app urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
]
```

**pages app urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('kontakt/', views.contact_view),
    path('o_nas/', views.about_view),
    path('', views.home_view),
]
```

**pages app views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home_view(reqest):
    return render(reqest, "index.html")
def about_view(reqest):
    return render(reqest, "about.html")
def contact_view(reqest):
    return render(reqest, "contact.html")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first: add a name to each route inside pages app urls.py.

- pages app urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('kontakt/', views.contact_view, name='contact'),
    path('o_nas/', views.about_view, name='about'),
    path('', views.home_view, name='home'),
]
```

Inside the HTML Template you can use the url tag in combination with the name of the route to assign the desired target to the href.

- HTML code fragment

```
<header>
    <nav class="headlist">
        <a href='{% url 'home' %}'><img id = "img1" src="{% static 'css/logo.png' %}" alt="logo"></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="{% url **Link to about_view** %}">O nas</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url **Link to contact_view** %}">Kontakt</a></li>
            <li><a>Zajęcia</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```